# Why is Capcom listed twice here?

Tags: copyright

On the [official Super Smash Bros. Ultimate website](https://www.smashbros.com/en_GB/index.html), there is a part in the footer that lists all the owners for the different characters that appear in the game. Capcom has Mega Man, Ryu and Ken represented in the game, but Capcom is listed twice in that footer: once as "CAPCOM CO., LTD." and once as "CAPCOM U.S.A., INC.".

What's the reason behind this? Are the characters owned by different branches of Capcom? The order in which the owners are listed matches when their character first appeared in the series. Mega Man appeared first in the base game of Super Smash Bros. 4 3DS/Wii U, with Ryu being added later as DLC, after Pac-Man (BANDAI NAMCO Entertainment Inc.) and after Shulk (MONOLITHSOFT). So if I read this correctly, the Mega Man franchise is owned by CAPCOM CO., LTD, while Street Fighter is owned by CAPCOM U.S.A., INC. ... Does that make sense?

Comment: They are obviously two different companies, hence they are listed two different times. Names mean very little if they don't refer to a specific legal object or a general defined class of object; "Capcom" is neither.

Answer (score 1):

Capcom's Japanese parent and its US subsidiary are obviously different companies and the copyright statements could be different depending on what is licensed. In particular, it's more likely that Capcom USA is listed because of Mega Man. The Mega Man character in Japan is known as Rock Man (hence, his partner "Roll"). It's also possible that any English logo rights are owned by the US branch.

Comment: But then why is there a gap between the two Capcoms? The way it's set up, it seems the US branch specifically owns the Street Fighter series for some reason. Otherwise they would be listed right after each other. I also checked the 3DS/Wii U site in the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150305040212/http://www.smashbros.com/us/) before all the DLC fighters were revealed (no Ryu yet) and CAPCOM U.S.A., INC. was not listed.

Comment: I don't presume to know how Capcom has organized itself and its copyrights. But I doubt a lot of thought goes into the listing order unless they have contracts about the order (actor billing for movies is an example of that).

Comment: I doubt the listing order is arbitrary, the order of the copyright owners matches the order in which their characters first appeared in the series.